# KendoUI Grid with MultiSelect, addNew item in MultiSelect

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-multiselect

In the sample i combinate kendoGrid with a kendoMultiSelect column.

my Sample: [kendoGrid with kendoMultiselect Sample](http://dojo.telerik.com/iWAxO/26)
Adding for new item works. But the dataBinding it does not work. As soon as you leave the field, the value is lost.

Comment: Cannot understand how to reproduce the issue. Can you provide the steps?

Comment: I cleaned the old version of Sample:

Comment: I cleaned the old version of Sample:
[kendoGrid with kendoMultiselect Sample Adding for new item](http://dojo.telerik.com/iWAxO/29)
Steps:
click into the column country
select a item => it works
click into the column country and type "Test 99"
click Add new item ==> it goes to datasource.add(); ==> and go to create on Server
-----------------------------------------------------------
this version it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned the old version of Sample:
[kendoGrid with kendoMultiselect Sample Adding for new item](http://dojo.telerik.com/iWAxO/29)
Steps:

- click into the column country select a item => it works
- click into the column country and type "Test 99"
- click Add new item ==> it goes to datasource.add(); ==> and go to create on Server

this version it works